# read images which start with certain string opencv - python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a folder which is containing thousands of images. I want to read only the images which start with a certain string, let's say *input*, how can I do this exactly ?

I am using *opencv*, so this is how I read all images

```
inputA_path = os.path.join(inputA_dir, '*g')
inputFilesA =glob.glob(inputA_path)

for f1 in inputFilesA:
    inputA = cv2.imread(f1)
```

Comment: Check this it might be helpful https://pymotw.com/2/glob/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use glob.glob right away and filter for files starting with *input* and ending with *g*.

```
inputFilesA = glob.glob(inputA_dir+"input*g")

for f1 in inputFilesA:
   inputA = cv2.imread(f1)
```